# Prove by induction $(6^ − 1)(7^ − 1)$ is a multiple of $30$ for all natural number $n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I've tried multiple approaches that worked for me in other exercises. But here I always get stuck here:

$$(6^{k+1} -1)(7^{k+1} -1)= (6\cdot6^k -1)(7\cdot7^k -1)= 6(6^k -1) 7(7^k-1)+11.$$

Proving different approaches I always end up in something like this, and I don't know how to advance any further. Can anyone give me any tips in what I am missing?

Comment: Can you show by induction that $6^n - 1$ is always a multiple of 5?

Comment: Note that $ ( 6 \cdot 6^k - 1 ) \neq 6 ( 6^k - 1) $. Can you fix the arithmetic?

Comment: first show by induction that $5$ divides $6^n-1$ and $6$ divides $7^n-1$, then since $\gcd(5,6)=1$, $5\cdot 6 = 30$ divides the product of the two.

Comment: $(a+1)^n \equiv 1 \pmod{a}.$

Comment: indeed (6⋅6k−1)≠6(6k−1) but (6⋅6k−1)=6(6k−1)+5. But since i couldn't go any further with that i guess it wasn't the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little tricky, but you can prove it like this:

1. Prove by induction that $(6^n - 1) = 5k$

If $n=1$, it's automatic.

Suppose $(6^n - 1) = 5k$.
Then
$$(6^{n+1}-1) = 6(6^n-\frac{1}{6}) = 6(6^n-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6}-\frac{5}{6}) = 6(6^n-1+\frac{5}{6}) = 6(5k+\frac{5}{6}) = 5(6k+1)$$

2. Prove by induction that $(7^n-1) = 6k$

If $n=1$, it's automatic.

Suppose $(7^n - 1) = 6k$.
Then
$$(7^{n+1}-1) = 7(7^n-\frac{1}{7}) = 7(7^n-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{6}{7}-\frac{6}{7}) = 7(7^n-1+\frac{6}{7}) = 7(6k+\frac{6}{7}) = 6(7k+1)$$

3. Finally,

$$(6^n-1)\cdot(7^n-1) = 5k_1\cdot6k_2 = 30k_1k_2 \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Answer (score 1):

$(6^n - 1)(7^n - 1) = ((5 + 1)^n - 1)((6 + 1)^n - 1)$

Comment: I'm really curious whether the people who downvoted this did it because they considered the answer as not helpful or because they considered it as too helpful. (Once you use the binomial formula for $(x+y)^n$, it *is* helpful.)

Answer (score 0):

We assume $30 \vert (6^n - 1)(7^n - 1) $ and apply induction:

$$ 30 \vert (6^{n + 1} - 1)(7^{n + 1} - 1)  $$
$$ 30 \vert (6^n - 1 + 5 \cdot 6^n)(7^n - 1 + 6 \cdot 7^n)  $$
$$ 30 \vert (6^n - 1)(7^n - 1) + (6^n - 1)\cdot 6 \cdot 7^n + 5 \cdot 6^n(7^n - 1) + 30 \cdot 6^n \cdot 7^n  $$

Now, it remains to show:

$$ 30 \vert (6^n - 1) 6 \cdot 7^n $$

or:

$$ 5 \vert 6^n - 1 $$

We do so inductively. We assume $5 \vert 6^n - 1$ and apply induction:

$$ 5 \vert 6^{n + 1} - 1 = 5 \vert 6^n - 1 + 5 \cdot 6^n $$

And so we conclude $30 \vert (6^n - 1)(7^n - 1)$ for all $n \geq 0$.